# Необходимо сложить цифры с которых начинаются повторяющиеся значения

Tags: python

```
my_list = ['10 Волокамск',
    '10 Белгородская область',
    '10 Ростов-на-Дону',
    '2 Барклай де Толли',
    '2 Барклай де Толли',
    '10 Орёл',
    '10 Нальчик',
    '10 50 лет первому полёту человека в космос',
    '2 Новороссийск',
    '2 Барклай де Толли',
    '10 Гатчина',
    '10 50 лет первому полёту человека в космос']

result = []

my_list.sort()

for i in range(0,len(my_list)-1):

               if my_list[i] == my_list[i+1]:
                   result.append(my_list[i])



print(result)
```

Comment: покажите пример желаемого результата, что должно в итоге получиться ?

Comment: В итоге должно получиться 14. Изначально значения в списке это монеты, и нужно сложить номинал повторяющихся

Comment: Я отсортировала повторяющиеся в итоге получилось  так: ['10 50 лет первому полёту человека в космос', '2 Барклай де Толли', '2 Барклай де Толли'] Теперь мне нужно сложить 10+2+2

Comment: если сложить повторяющиеся номиналы то будет 26. 3 х 2 Барклай де Толли + 2 х 10 50 лет первому полёту человека в космос

Comment: Я удалила дубли. Дубли мне не нужны

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Почему тогда `2 Барклай де Толли` дважды?

Comment: Сейчас подробно напишу, чтобы суть была понята всей задачи. Прошу прощения!

Comment: У Петра скопилась горка юбилейных монет, среди которых попадаются дубликаты. Монеты попадаются разных номиналов и с изображениями разных городов или людей. Пётр хочет оставить по одной монете каждого типа, а остальными расплатиться в магазине. Посчитайте, монеты на какую сумму Пётр может потратить, оставив по одному экземпляру каждого типа монет. Гарантируется, что все монеты – целочисленные, и номинал монеты стоит на первом месте. Номинал отделяется от названия пробельным символом.

Answer (score 2):

Если чуть испраить ваш код то получится так:

```
my_list = ['10 Волокамск',
    '10 Белгородская область',
    '10 Ростов-на-Дону',
    '2 Барклай де Толли',
    '2 Барклай де Толли',
    '10 Орёл',
    '10 Нальчик',
    '10 50 лет первому полёту человека в космос',
    '2 Новороссийск',
    '2 Барклай де Толли',
    '10 Гатчина',
    '10 50 лет первому полёту человека в космос']

result = 0

my_list.sort()

for i in range(0,len(my_list)-1):
    if my_list[i] == my_list[i+1]:
        result += int(my_list[i].split()[0])
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce

my_list = ['10 Волокамск',
    '10 Белгородская область',
    '10 Ростов-на-Дону',
    '2 Барклай де Толли',
    '2 Барклай де Толли',
    '10 Орёл',
    '10 Нальчик',
    '10 50 лет первому полёту человека в космос',
    '2 Новороссийск',
    '2 Барклай де Толли',
    '10 Гатчина',
    '10 50 лет первому полёту человека в космос']
    

print(reduce(lambda s, el: s + int(el[0].split()[0]) * (el[1] - 1), Counter(my_list).items(), 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно без дополнительных библиотек и сортировки через создание уникального сета, подсчета его вхождений (числа монет) в `my_list` через метод списка `list.count()` с фильтром на число монет больше одной:

```
my_list = ['10 Волокамск',
    '10 Белгородская область',
    '10 Ростов-на-Дону',
    '2 Барклай де Толли',
    '2 Барклай де Толли',
    '10 Орёл',
    '10 Нальчик',
    '10 50 лет первому полёту человека в космос',
    '2 Новороссийск',
    '2 Барклай де Толли',
    '10 Гатчина',
    '10 50 лет первому полёту человека в космос']

print(sum(int(s.split(' ')[0]) * (my_list.count(s) - 1) 
          for s in set(my_list) if my_list.count(s) > 1))
# 14
```